# Coloring points instead of lines in interaction.plot (R)I

Tags: r, plot

I want to make an interaction plot in R as in the example

http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/week4.html#interactionplot

except instead of coloring the lines I want to color the points by some attribute other than the number.  The desired functionality would look like

```
blood_pressure = ...  # this will be the x-axis
age_bucket = ... # this will be the interaction-level
gender = ... # color boys blue, girls red
stroke_rate = ... # y-axis

interaction.plot(blood_pressure, age_bucket, stroke_rate, col=gender, type="b"...
```

Except color=gender actually does what I want

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `interaction.plot` actually relies on `tapply()` to compute aggregated summary measures (mean or median). As `interaction.plot` just calls `matplot`, you can use the latter directly if you like, or summarize your data with [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) and plot the results with [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) (more flexible).

```
# consider the 64x4 dataset OrchardSprays and create a fake
# two-levels factor, say grp, which is in correspondence to rowpos odd/even values
grp <- gl(2, 1, 8, labels=letters[1:2])
# the following won't work (due to color recycling)
with(OrchardSprays, 
     interaction.plot(treatment, rowpos, decrease, 
                      type="b", pch=19, lty=1, col=as.numeric(colpos), legend=F))
# what is used to draw the 8 lines is computed from
with(OrchardSprays, 
     tapply(decrease, list(treatment=treatment, rowpos=rowpos), mean))
# the following will work, though
with(OrchardSprays, 
     interaction.plot(treatment, rowpos, decrease, 
                      type="b", pch=19, lty=1, col=as.numeric(grp), legend=F))
```

In short, assuming you can find an adequate mapping between `gender` and your trace factor (`age_bucket`), you need to construct a vector of colors of size `nlevels(age_bucket)`.